# Mixture model when K=1

Tags: probability, gaussian-mixture-distribution, mixture-distribution

Assume that I want to estimate the parameters of a distribution like for example the Gaussian distribution, but I have the code only for the estimation of the parameters of a mixture of Gaussian distributions.

Can I use this code setting K=1? Is a 1-cluster solution of a mixture distribution the same of a single distribution?

I know that it might be a silly question but I am having hard times trying to answering it. Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to estimate the parameters of a multivariate gaussian distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they will be the same - all data points will be from the same component, a single Gaussian.

But it’s surprising that you have code for a mixture of Gaussian and not code for fitting a Gaussian, as that code is usually used as part of the mixture estimation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The fact is that I don't want to get confused deleting parts which are important in the code of the mixture... but anyway the problem is solved I just out K=1..